# List table name AND cell in last row and column

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to list all table names in a sheet, together with the table's corresponding cell in the last row and column. The below code finds the table names in sheet "A1.6Laster" (Except table "Lastkategori") and then lists them in sheet "A1.6.5Lastkombinationer".

Since I can add/delete tables i sheet "A1.6Laster", the list is first deleted/cleared.

In other words; the below code work fine listing the names of the tables, but in the column next to the name list I want each table's corresponding cell in the last row and column to be listed as well. Do I need to add some code in the For Each loop?

Any input is welcome, and please ask if you need further information!

```
Sub Laster()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim SearchText As String
Dim GCell As Range

SearchText = "Laster"
Set GCell = Worksheets("A1.6.5Lastkombinationer").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(0)
Set wsSummary = Worksheets("A1.6.5Lastkombinationer")
Set ws = Worksheets("A1.6Laster")

With Worksheets("A1.6.5Lastkombinationer").ListObjects("Laster").DataBodyRange
If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
  .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
End If
End With
Worksheets("A1.6.5Lastkombinationer").ListObjects("Laster").DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents

lRow = GCell.Row
    For Each tbl In Worksheets("A1.6Laster").ListObjects
        If tbl.Name <> "Lastkategori" Then
        lRow = lRow + 1
        With wsSummary
            .Cells(lRow, "A") = tbl.Name
        End With
        End If
    Next tbl

ws.ListObjects("Lastkategori").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Copy
wsSummary.ListObjects("Laster").DataBodyRange(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming when you say last row and column means the bottom right hand corner cell of each table.

Add the following snippet within With wsWsummary ... End With. What it does is it takes the range of cells for each table's data range and gets the last row's last column and spits out the data in that cell into the column next to the table's name.

```
        Dim r As Range
        Dim last As Range

        Set r = tbl.DataBodyRange
        Set last = r.Cells(r.Rows.Count, r.Columns.Count)
        ws.Cells(lRow, "B").Value = last
```

Comment: Hello cbasah. Thanks for your answer. I get an idea of how it works! However, in column "B" it now inserts the row cell number (fx row 11) and in column "C" it inserts column cell number (fx column 6). What I would like is to just insert the data within the cell of the bottom right hand cell in column "B" of each table.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just deleted "ws.Cells(lRow, "C").Value = last.Column" and changed "ws.Cells(lRow, "B").Value = last.Row" to "ws.Cells(lRow, "B").Value = last".
Thank you still!